# Convert MySQL database from latin1 to utf8mb4 - and take care of German umlauts

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, encoding, utf-8

I am using 5.6.28 MySQL Community Server to host WordPress + ProPhoto blog in German language at CentOS 6.7 Linux server:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_blog        |
+-----------------------+
| wp_commentmeta        |
| wp_comments           |
| wp_links              |
| wp_options            |
| wp_postmeta           |
| wp_posts              |
| wp_term_relationships |
| wp_term_taxonomy      |
| wp_terms              |
| wp_usermeta           |
| wp_users              |
+-----------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then recently I have started developing a Russian language app and had to change MySQL settings to [utf8mb4](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) encoding in **/etc/my.cnf**:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake=FALSE
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Now I have a minor problem with the first database that it is still shown as **latin1**:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     | HOW TO CONVERT?
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the best way to convert a **latin1** database to **utf8mb4** please?

And how to ensure that the German umlaut characters ( `ä ö ü` ) are converted properly in the process?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two possible questions here, and they have two different answers --

**How do I make all new tables utf8mb4**

It can be done (for one database) while creating a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    DEFAULT COLLATE       utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

You can `ALTER` a database (similar syntax), but that only provides a *default* for *future* tables.

There are bugs relating to inheriting from the 'server' variables:  http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=3811 , so I suggest that you simply be explicit on each database.

**How do I convert existing latin1 tables**

If you have a table declared to be `latin1` and correctly contains latin1 bytes, and you would like to change all the char/text columns to utf8...

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

This changes the definition and actively changes the necessary bytes in the columns.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY col1 ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

is similar to the above, but works only one column at a time, and needs
exactly the right stuff in the MODIFY clause.  Hence, it would be quite tedious.  However, it is useful if you want to change only some of the columns.

Comment: So mysqldump, then dropping and creating a new database is not a good way here?

Comment: Dumping and reload would work -- _if_ you get the character sets changed at the right places.  mysqldump has a argment; mysql has an argument, etc.  Get them wrong an you will a mess.  (Sorry, I do not know precisely what to do.)

Comment: To check... latin1 for `äöü` is hex `E4F6FC`; utf8/utf8mb4 is `C3A4C3B6C3BC`.

Comment: For dump+reload you probably would need to either edit the `CHARACTER SET` specified in the dump or `CREATE` the tables separately.  (Again, I am weak on the details.)